# dividir um array em várias partes

Tags: c

Existe alguma forma de ter acesso a apenas uma parte especifica de um array em c? Por exemplo, em python é possível eu acessar uma parte específica de um array.

```
array[10] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
array[4:8] = 5,6,7,8
```

Queria saber se tem algo parecido em c, preciso passar uma parte especifica de um array para uma função.
Meu array é uma matriz de string. Assim:

```
char** string = = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char *));
```

Queria passar para uma função a matriz da posição 0 até a posição 500.

Comment: Como é essa função? Ela pega o tamanho da array como argumento?

Comment: É uma função do MPI, a função Broadcast, queria mandar um pedaço da matriz para cada processo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode ver uma array do C como sendo um mero ponteiro para o primeiro elemento. Ela nem mesmo guarda a informação de quantos elementos existem. Assim, geralmente as funções que pegam um array como argumento pegam também o tamanho do array como um segundo argumento. Exemplo:

```
int* array = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));

func(array, 1000);
```

Isso significa que você pode brincar com os argumentos passados para a função. Por exemplo, para pegar apenas os primeiros 500 ítens:

```
func(array, 500);
```

E os últimos 500:

```
func(array+500, 500);
```

Apenas cuidado para não passar mais do que a array tem. Não permita que a função leia dados fora da memória da array.

Answer (score 0):

Como em C, a variavel só armazena o começo do vetor.
Dá pra você brincar com a função `mempcy` e copiar um bloco de memória

```
#define NUM 1000

char** string = malloc(NUM * sizeof(char *));
char** parte1 = malloc((int)(NUM/2) * sizeof(char *));
char** parte2 = malloc((int)(NUM/2) * sizeof(char *));

memcpy(parte1, string, (int)(NUM/2) * sizeof(int)); 
memcpy(parte2, &string + (int)(NUM/2), (int)(NUM/2) * sizeof(int));
```

Assim você vai ter duas novas strings. Uma contendo os 500 primeiros e a outra os 500 ultimos elementos da string original.

Comment: O que acontece se `NUM` for impar?

Comment: Oi vhbsouza! Tem um errinho de digitação na resposta: está escrito `mempcy` no primeiro parágrafo. Agora, sobre o comentário do Guilherme Bernal, realmente se NUM for ímpar, você terá sérios problemas: vai faltar copiar 1 elemento. Lembrando que 9 / 2, com inteiros, dá 4! Assim, você só copiaria 8 elementos. É preciso fazer algo assim: no `size` do primeiro `memcpy`, utilizar `NUM/2`, já no `size` do segundo, utilizar `NUM-(NUM/2)` :) Além disso, no segundo `memcpy`, pode retirar o operador `&` da variável `string`. E em ambos `memcpy`, os `sizeof(int)` deveriam ser `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: de fato, @carlosrafaelgn. Obg pelas observações. Eu esbocei rapidamente e esqueci de pensar no caso do NUM impar e quanto ao `sizeof` eu fiz no meu pc usando inteiros dai quando colei o codigo aqui usei `string` pra passar pro caso dele. Pura falta de atenção.